# How to improve performance on mongoDB search in collections with millions of records and each with a lot of searchable attributes?

Tags: mongodb

There is a collection of approximately 20 million records and each with about 200 searchable attributes.

Example:

```
{atrib001:"abc", atrib002:"123", atrib003:"1x3"... atrib200:"1zz"}
```

The application that does read operation allows it to be dynamically assembled, according to user-desired options.

How is it possible or what the recommendation for the creation of indexes in mongoDB to improve the performance of this type of read operation ? Moreover, it is viable to create an index for each attribute, in which case would be 200 indexes, and trust that the mongoDB choose the best of them?

Comment: imho this sounds like a case for kv or columnar nosql and not document nosql. at least without further digging